# how to create temporary folder in java and add files inside it

Tags: java, file, rest, zip, directory

i'm trying to develop a REST service, and i managed to return all the data which i need. but I want to create a temporary filder and add some files inside it and put all these objects(folder with its files) in zip file, and when the REST service is called the zip file will be downloaded.
here's the code:

```
public class rest {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "file.xml";

    @GET
    @Path( "/GetSequenceId/{id}" )
    @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
    @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_XML )
    // @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response showFileStoreDetails( @PathParam( "id" ) String id)
            throws ArchiveException, IOException {

        Response response = null;
        File file = new File( FILE_PATH );
        // String feeds = null;
        Sequence feedData = null;
        Step step = new Step();
        Liststeps listStep = new Liststeps();
        Attachement attachement = new Attachement();
        List<String> listOfAttachement = new ArrayList<String>();
        // List<attachement> listAttachementd = null;
        // File file = new File( "file.xml" );
        // Response response = null;
        // System.out.println( listOfAttachement );
        try {
            /*
             * Database database = new Database(); Connection connection =
             * database.Get_Connection();
             */
            feedData = listStep.getSteps( Integer.parseInt( id ) );
            listOfAttachement = listStep.getAttachementId();
            System.out.println( listOfAttachement );
            System.out.println( "------------Debut---------------------------------------" );
            for ( String att : listOfAttachement ) {
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost", 27017 );
                DB mongoDB = mongoClient.getDB( "tutorial" );

                // Let's store the standard data in regular collection
                DBCollection collection = mongoDB.getCollection( "filestore" );

                /// logger.info( "Inside downloadFilebyID..." );
                // logger.info( "ID: " + id );

                BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
                query.put( "_id", att );
                // System.out.println( "Mongo_ID :" +
                // att.getIdMongo().toString() );
                DBObject doc = collection.findOne( query );
                DBCursor cursor = collection.find( query );

                if ( cursor.hasNext() ) {

                    Set<String> allKeys = doc.keySet();
                    HashMap<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for ( String key : allKeys ) {
                        fields.put( key, doc.get( key ).toString() );
                    }

                    /*
                     * logger.info( "description: " + fields.get( "description"
                     * ) ); logger.info( "department: " + fields.get(
                     * "department" ) ); logger.info( "file_year: " +
                     * fields.get( "file_year" ) );
                     */
                    // logger.info( "filename: " + fields.get( "filename" ) );

                    GridFS fileStore = new GridFS( mongoDB, "filestore" );
                    GridFSDBFile gridFile = fileStore.findOne( query );

                    InputStream in = gridFile.getInputStream();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int data = in.read();
                    while ( data >= 0 ) {
                        out.write( (char) data );
                        data = in.read();
                    }
                    out.flush();
                    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok( out.toByteArray() );
                    builder.header( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fields.get( "filename" ) );
                    response = builder.build();


                }
            }

            // ProjectManager projectManager = new ProjectManager();

            // feedData = listStep.getSteps( Integer.parseInt( id ) );
            System.out.println( "--------------fin-----------------------------------" );

            // listAttachementd = listStep.getAttachement();
            // StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            // Gson gson = new Gson();
            // System.out.println( gson.toJson( feedData ) );

            // feeds = gson.toJson( feedData );
            // String xml = org.json.XML.toString(gson);
            // XStream xstream = new XStream();
            // File file = new File( "input.xml" );
            // try {
            //
            // // File file = new File( "input.xml" );
            // JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( Sequence.class
            // );
            // Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            //
            // // output pretty printed
            // jaxbMarshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
            // true );
            //
            // jaxbMarshaller.marshal( feedData, file );
            // jaxbMarshaller.marshal( feedData, System.out );
            //
            // } catch ( JAXBException e ) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            // }

        } catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
            System.out.println( e );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok( (Object) file );
         * response.header( "Content-Disposition",
         * "attachment; filename=\"sequence.xml\"" ); System.out.println( file
         * );
         * 
         * return response.build();
         */
        return response;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can directly create folder, add files and zip it on file system. Then you can use HttpServletResponse OutputStream. In this way all for your file processing would be done and you can simple load zip file in HttpServletResponse OutputStream and finally delete all the processing files from file system and give user stream for download

Example :

```
`@GET
@Path("/{key}")
public Response download(@PathParam("key") String key,
                         @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try {
        //Get your File or Object from wherever you want...
        //you can use the key parameter to indentify your file
        //otherwise it can be removed
        //let's say your file is called "object"
        response.setContentLength((int) object.getContentLength());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + object.getName());
        ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bbuf = new byte[(int) object.getContentLength() + 1024];
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                object.getDataInputStream());
        int length = 0;
        while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
            outStream.write(bbuf, 0, length);
        }
        in.close();
        outStream.flush();
    } catch (S3ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

`

Comment: thank u for the answer, but how i can zip all the files, the zip file must create dynamically

Comment: See creating it dynamically would not be possible because for creating this scenario you have to :  Create a folder, Then add files to it, Then for zipping it you have to pass folder path. So I recommend you to use a one common location create folder by appending time-stamp to its name and process it. It will avoid duplicate for concurrent request also. I have implemented same my self for this scenario.

Comment: I have a list as an object

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary folder by

`Files.createTempDirectory(prefix, FileAttribute[] attrs);`

Then with ZipOutputStream create zip file